# How can I indicate the Git username and password in Capistrano's deploy.rb?

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano, automated-deploy

I'm using github to store the repository, and I'm reading [Deploy with Capistrano](http://help.github.com/capistrano/):

> Remote caching will keep a local git repo on the server you’re deploying to and simply
>   run a fetch from that rather than an entire clone".

Since the server where I'm deploying is "my" **shared host**, I must have git installed there.

When we do that, we normally define a git username and git password.
Where should we place those on this deploy.rb file?

So far I have:

```
set :application, "mysite.dev"
set :user, "myuser"
set :repository, "git@github.com:gituser/gitproject.git"
role :web, "dev.mysite.pt"
set :deploy_to, "/home/mysite/www/dev"
set :use_sudo, false
set :scm, :git
set :branch, 'master'

#set :deploy_via, :copy
#set :copy_cache, true
#set :copy_exclude, %w(.git)

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

task :create_symlinks, :roles =&gt; :web do
run "rm #{current_release}/public/.htaccess"
run "ln -s #{current_release}/production/.htaccess
#{current_release}/public/.htaccess"
end

after "deploy:finalize_update", :create_symlinks
```

**Shouldn't we place, somewhere, the references to my shared host git password on the deploy.rb file somehow ?**

I have the deploy server user:

```
set :user, "myuser"
```

Is this password the one from github user, or should we here put our shared host password?

```
set :scm_passphrase, "p@ssw0rd"  # The deploy user's password
```

Comment: if we had to set a password in a file that could publicly be visible on any repository, then using Capistrano or other deployment method, would'nt make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use your local keys (from development machine) add this on the beginning of the script:

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

The `set :user, 'myuser'` is user name of the Linux box you are connecting to.