# Connect to github from linode with Capistrano deploy gives permission denied to public key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, ssh

This is my first time using linode and uploading a Rails app to a VPS, so I might of skipped something obvious.

I followed two tutorials
[Ryan Bates video to deploying to a vps](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=comments)
and
[David's answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444105/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-to-a-vps-or-dedicated-server/13444106#13444106)

I am at the point where I want to deploy my rails app on Linode (Ubuntu 13.10)

When I execute the command `bundle exec cap deploy:update`

I get the errors that Linode cannot connect to github due to a public key

```
user:my-app User$ bundle exec cap deploy:update
  * 2014-02-12 17:19:46 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2014-02-12 17:19:46 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:user/my-app.git master"
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/user/apps/my-app/releases/20140212091953; true"
    servers: ["XXX.XXX.XX.XX"]
    [XXX.XXX.XX.XX] executing command
    command finished in 4607ms
Command git ls-remote git@github.com:user/my-app.git master returned status code pid 1529 exit 128
```

On my local machine I have no problem to commit and push my app on Github and I have RSA Keys on my local computer. It just asks me to login with my username and password each time I push my app.

On linode from the shell, I can connect to github by using `ssh -vT git@github.com`. I do have the RSA keys on the linode server and I added the ssh-agent using `ssh-add`

my deploy.rb

```
set :application, "my-app"
set :user, "user"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 3
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:user/#{application}.git"
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
# ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :branch, "master"
```

I am a bit at a loss.

**EDIT:** I have a private repository

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5485395/1120015 ?

Comment: Hello Uri, thanks for the response. I am pretty sure it is not a passphrase issue because in this test event, there isn't any passphrase.

Comment: OK. In your deploy.rb it says `set :repository, "git@github.com:user/#{application}.git"`. You renamed it to `user` for here right? In your actual deploy.rb, it is the real repository location...

Comment: yes I renamed it here on stackoverflow, the real username and app name are properly written in the cap file. I am thinking the issue is more github related than cap, but again I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution to this github connection. I actually have another problem with the deployment where the bundle install fails. Anyways here is what I learned and I hope it will help others.

What you need to know:

1. With Capistrano when you wish to push your public or private Github
   repository onto your VPS server, you need to make sure that BOTH your
   server and your computer has an SSH access with Github.
2. Even if you can `git push origin master` it doesn't mean you have SSH
   access with Github. Here is how you troubleshoot:

**A) Make sure you can SSH access from your computer**

1. Make sure you have Git installed on your machine [Set up Git
   tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)
2. Make sure that you have an SSH Key on your local machine (with Linux
   or Mac)

   `cd ~/.ssh` then
   `ls -a`

   and look for the files `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`
3. If you don't have these `rsa` files, follow this tutorial
   [Generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)
4. Copy your SSH key

   `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
   `# Copies the contents of the id_rsa.pub file to your clipboard`
5. Login with your browser on http://www.github.com and go to
   your_username -> edit profile -> settings -> ssh keys
   https://github.com/settings/ssh. Click the button Add keys, add the name that identifies your comptuter and paste the key code that you previously copied.
6. Make sure you have SSH Agent on. In Terminal type

   `ssh-add #enter a passphrase if you want to (recommended)`
7. Test if you can SSH with Github

   `ssh git@github.com`

The first time it may ask you to accept the connection.
You should get the following response

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

You can also make sure that your id_rsa is properly found by running

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
# make sure that this line is not -1 (it means it couldn't find the file)
=> debug1: identity file /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
```

Now you shouldn't have `permission denied (Public Key)`

**B) Make sure you can SSH access from your server**

1. Run `ssh root@your_server_ip_address` if you didn't setup a user on your server or `ssh username@your_server_ip_address`. You will then be within the server shell and you want to repeat the same process for your computer.

**NOTE:** The server SSH Keys will be different than your computer. That means that on Github you need to add 2 SSH Keys, one for your computer and one for your server. That is why you need to repeat the process on both machines. Also to keep it simple, do not try to have more than one SSH Key on each machine.

**NOTE 2:** In your server after you generated your SSH key, to copy it run the command `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Once both your computer and the server are accepted on Github, then you can update your rails app using capistrano and your Github repository. Yay!

Answer (score 6):

I just moved from Linux to Mac OSx. Thus, I have imported whole `.ssh` folder from linux to mac. While moving from linux to linux it worked, but to make it work on Mac, I had also to run:

`ssh-add`

That's the whole fix ;) See http://peteoliveira.com/deploying-with-capistrano-3-failing-permission-denied-publickey/ for more info.